# Ocaml - differences between compiler and manual

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml

So I was reading http://www.podval.org/~sds/ocaml-sucks.html, which includes this quote (in the context of problems with ocaml):

> there are actually three mildly different syntaxes:
>
> - the official one is described in the manual
> - a superset thereof is accepted by the compiler ocamlc
> - something similar (but ever so    slightly different) is accepted by    the preprocessor Camlp4 (e.g., it    accepts List.map [1;2;3]
>     ~f:fun    x -> x, which is also accepted by the    top-level, but not
>     the    compiler)

What are examples of ocaml code fragments that are accepted by the ocamlc but do not match the manual?

PS - I'm mainly interested in OCaml 4.00.1, but previous versions are also interesting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One funny example, in the interest of curiosity only:

```
                  OCaml version 4.00.0

# type 'a weird_list =
    | ()
    | :: of 'a * 'a weird_list;;
type 'a weird_list = () | :: of 'a * 'a weird_list
# 1::2::3::();;
- : int weird_list = :: (1, :: (2, :: (3, ())))
```

The differences between Camlp4 and the OCaml compiler are sometimes bugs, but most often explained by the difference in parser technology: if you write an idiomatic LR parser and a LL parser for the same language with mildly annoying syntax subtleties, you should not expect both to match perfectly. I don't think this is a problem in practice (but in practice most people don't use Camlp4).

Answer (score 2):

This page is quite old, not sure, it is still true for all points.

The third item is false considering ocaml 4.00 toplevel (considering too, that the order of parameters of List.map is wrong...):

```
 $ List.map  ~f:fun x -> x [1;2;3];;
 Error: Syntax error        
 $ List.map ~f:(fun x -> x) [1;2;3];;
 File "", line 1, characters  12-24:
 Error: The function applied to this argument has type 'a list -> 'b list 
 This argument cannot be applied with label ~f
```

AFAIK, the toplevel use the same code than ocaml to parse the code...